# Login Expire session issue in .net core(blazor)

Tags: .net, blazor, logout, expired-sessions, expired-cookies

When I log in and set expire time to 12 hours I get logged out after 20 or 30 minutes and redirect to the login page. I don't know the reason for that.
This is my code

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>{
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, FullName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.Username),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, "Active"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.UserId.ToString()),
            };
AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(12),
                AllowRefresh =true,
            };
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
ClaimsPrincipal cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
awaitHttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,cp,authProperties);
```

[see the screen shoot cookie expire time set 12 hours in utc datetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPs1H.png)

I am trying to log out after 12 hours but I get logged out after 20 minutes

Comment: Try setting the cookie [ExpireTimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.expiretimespan?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Did you check the Webserver session timeout? sounds like your web server uses default session timeout of 20 minutes